# Order of multiplication of matrices $A$ and $A^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've come across a problem where I need to find a matrix $A^{n+1}$, where I was given matrices $A$ and $A^n$. I multiplied them like this: $A^n\cdot A$, but I was obviously wrong since the result is adequate for $A\cdot A^n$.

Now, I know that $A\cdot B\neq B\cdot A$, but how would I decide the order of multiplication if I was "only" given the exponent, as in this case? Should I always put a matrix with a smaller exponent first? If so, why?

Comment: $AB$ is fortunately not always diffrent from $BA$. In particular iris not for your specific case! Here thé equality stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powers of a single object commute.
\begin{align*}
A^m A^n &= \underbrace{A \times \cdots \times A}_{\text{$m$ copies of $A$}} \times \underbrace{A \times \cdots \times A}_{\text{$n$ copies of $A$}}  \\
    &= \underbrace{A \times \cdots \times A}_{\text{$m+n$ copies of $A$}}  \\
    &= \underbrace{A \times \cdots \times A}_{\text{$n+m$ copies of $A$}}  \\
    &= A^n A^m  \text{.}
\end{align*}

In your particular example,
\begin{align*}
A \times A^n &= A \times \underbrace{A \times \cdots \times A}_{\text{$n$ copies of $A$}}  \\
    &= \underbrace{A \times \cdots \times A}_{\text{$n+1$ copies of $A$}}  \\
    &= \underbrace{A \times \cdots \times A}_{\text{$n$ copies of $A$}} \times A  \\
    &= A^n \times A  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Matrix multiplication is not commutative operation but $A\cdot A^n=A^n\cdot A=A^{n+1}$ (Use induction to prove it). So you are not wrong.

Comment: I'd say rather that matrix multiplication is not *generally* commutative

Answer (score 2):

Noncommutativity doesn't mean that two matrices can't *ever* commute ;)

$A\cdot A$ is obviously a commutative product, since both factors are the same.

Same goes for iterated products: in $A\cdot A\cdot\ ...\ \cdot A$ you can shuffle any two factors as you like. It thus make sense to shorten this expression as $A^n$. This clearly means that your product is in fact commutative, that is: $$A\cdot A^n=A^n\cdot A.$$

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is associative. So here $$A^{n+1} = A^n \cdot A=A \cdot A^n$$